# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'all' c#

Tags: c#, command-line, command, command-prompt, prompt

I am trying to execute a command through c#. I pass a command as a parameter through a function which then executes it on my terminal in VS Code. When I pass the command `'ps'` it works, but when I pass the command `'ls - all'` it gives me the error: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'all'. I think it probably has to do something with the space, but I'm not sure. I don't know how to solve it. This is the function I use to pass the command and execute it:

```
public void ExecuteCommand(string key) {
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            try {
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.FileName = @"powershell.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = "/c " + key;
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
                process.Close();

            }
            catch {
                Console.WriteLine("Error occured");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Command executed");
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the command `ls -Force` to list all the files including the hidden files.`ls -al` works in linux.